# How to get IP address of client in PHP for the requests made via AMP email

Tags: php, apache, ip, amp-html, amp-email

I have implemented AMP email, so when the client submits any data via `amp-form` from inside of the email body, the request goes to google and google submits data to my server via an HTTP request but as AMP requests come to my server from Google server instead of the client's browser, I am not able to get Client's IP via normal PHP `$_SERVER` variable.

Is there any workaround for AMP EMAILS by which I can Client's IP in my PHP Apache backend?

Below is the code I am using to get IP as of now, but not able to get client IP in any of the `$_SERVER` key:

```php
function get_ip_address()
{
    $str="";
    foreach (array('HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED', 'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_FORWARDED', 'REMOTE_ADDR') as $key){
        if (array_key_exists($key, $_SERVER) === true)
        {
            foreach (explode(',', $_SERVER[$key]) as $ip)
            {
                $ip = trim($ip); // just to be safe
        
                if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE) !== false)
                {
                    $str .= $key." => ".$ip."    ";;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $str;
}
```

---

**Edit:**
As per [Su Zhang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1397618/su-zhang)'s comment over [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66764427/8494462), we can not get IP of the user due to privacy concerns, So a solution/workaround where I can get a nearby IP as per geolocation of the client will also work for me.

Comment: You will have to put the client IP into one of the fields of your form to begin with, so that when Google passes the data on to your server, you can find it in there.

Comment: @CBroe , Even if I create a field in my `amp-form`, how this field can be filled with client's IP at the time of form submission?

Comment: You need server-side code, to determine the client IP in the first place (basically, what you had above already.) Then, if you can populate fields in the amp-form from your server-side code directly (don’t know, I don’t work with them), do that - otherwise, you will probably have to take a “detour” via JavaScript; make the determined IP address available to your script (create JS variable, with PHP), and put it into the target field on the client side.

Comment: With server-side code, it's not possible as the value of the variable will be calculated at the time of email sending so I can get my server's IP at that time, and including that will not benefit. I can not add JS add code as AMP doesn't allow external scripts. As per the doc: **Only AMP scripts for supported components can be included in AMP Emails**

Comment: But the user requests the amp page _from_ your server in the first place, no? That would be the time to determine their IP address then.

Comment: @CBroe No, the User doesn't request for amp-email, at least in my case. It's sent by backend using cron-worker. Even if it was possible, I needed the IP of the user at the time of form submission, not of form request.

Answer (score 2):

AMP email providers don't disclose the IP address of the user or else it would be a privacy leak. There's no way you can get the IP address of the user via form submission.

Comment: How can it be a privacy leak as the user agrees on some conditions while enabling dynamic email? Can you please provide any supporting statement given by google or official documentation?

Comment: What conditions are you referring you? There should be no condition that says users may expose their IP address for using dynamic emails. Most implementations of emails protect users on this front by proxying resources in the email. For example, Gmail does this for images: "Senders can’t use image loading to get information about your computer or location."
httpss://support.google.com/mail/answer/145919?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&oco=0 and the same thing applies for amp-form submissions within the email.

Comment: I got it, Thank you so much. But I am keeping the question open so that if anyone has any workaround to get nearby IP(geo location wise) if not exact, I'll update my question according to that..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to pull a JSON file for an empty function and attach it to the user.

Even if the user doesn't submit anything, if the user "activates" something in the AMP email that triggers this pull, you will have the IP.